# HIbernate Search not returning search results on primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using HIbernate search(5.8.2). The search works smoothly on every field except for the primary key. It returns an empty list when I pass anything to it. I followed the hibernate documentation, used @documentId annotation for primary key. What am I missing?

Here's my model:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "MAIN",schema="maindb")
public class MAIN implements Serializable {

@Id
@DocumentId
private String poNo; // my primary key which has values like "PO123"

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String postatus;
```

My search function:

```
public List<?> search(String poNumber, String status) {

QueryBuilder qb = 
fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MAIN.class).get();

BooleanQuery.Builder finalLuceneQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

org.hibernate.query.Query hibQuery = 
fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery.build(),MAIN.class);

org.apache.lucene.search.Query querypono1 = 
qb2.simpleQueryString().onField("poNo").matching(poNumber)
.createQuery();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryStatus =
qb.simpleQueryString().onField("po01_status")
.matching("postatus").createQuery();

finalLuceneQuery.add(querypono1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
finalLuceneQuery.add(queryStatus , BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

hibQuery.setFirstResult(0);
List<?> resultArchive = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        result = hibQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // log.log(ERROR, "ERROR FETCHING RESULT LIST FROM DATABASE");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that "PO123" is transformed to "po123" by the simple query string parser. I wonder why, I have to check that, it's probably a bug, or it's at least an unexpected behavior.

That being said, you shouldn't use the simpleQuery() entry point for an exact matching.

Replace:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query querypono1 = qb2.simpleQueryString().onField("poNo").matching(poNumber).createQuery();
```

By:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query querypono1 = qb2.keyword().onField("poNo").matching(poNumber).createQuery();
```

(keyword() instead of simpleQueryString())

I will follow up on this issue though as it's not the behavior I would have expected. Thanks for raising it.

-> JIRA issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3039 , will be included in the upcoming 5.10.0.Final.

Comment: Thank a lot  @Guillaume Smet. It's able to search now.